# Memory Leak in Firebase with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with Firebase when trying to load orders (20K nodes) by using the "child_added" event. Memory consumption increases and never goes down again. Once I stop the nodejs script, it goes back to normal.

My problem is that I'm running this script on a nodejs server (at startup), so, the memory on the server goes up and never goes down again.

tried to generate heap snapshot of memory after retrieving all children of the "orders" node. It showed that most memory allocation is happening inside objects:

- LLRBNode => 30%
- (string) => 34%
- LeafNode => 20%

which are basically members of the "sOrder" Firebase snapshot object. My original code was running without using "global.gc", but I added that to make sure Garbage Collector is running and in both cases, the same memory problem is happening.

I use the script like this:

```
node --expose-gc orders_load.js
```

I don't use debug to reproduce this case. My sample code:

```
console.log( "starting... " );
try
{
    let i = 1;
    firebase.database().ref("orders").on( "child_added", ( sOrder ) =>
    {
        console.log( "** " + i++ );
        if ( global.gc )
        {
            if( i % 1000 == 0 )
            {
                console.log( "running garbage collector" );
                global.gc();
            }
        }
        else
            console.log( 'Garbage collection unavailable.' );
    } );
}
catch( err )
{
    console.log( `EXCEPTION-%s`, err.message );
}
```

my "orders" node has 20K records and once I run the code above, the free memory goes down from 2181 Mb to 1426 Mb (755 Mb of memory). Any idea why the snapshot object of all my orders seem to be kept in memory even after callback function for the "child_added" event is finished?

firebase-admin: 6.4.0
nodejs: v11.6.0

===========================
After applying some hints from **Frank** below, I ended up with this code:

```
let i = 1;

function child_added( sOrder )
{
    console.log( "** " + i++ + " %s", sOrder.key );
}

console.log( "starting... " );
try
{
    firebase.database().ref("orders").once( "value", ( sOrders ) =>
    {
        sOrders.forEach( child_added );

        process.nextTick( () =>
        {
            firebase.database().ref("orders").limitToLast(1).on( "child_added", ( sOrder ) =>
            {
                child_added( sOrder );
            } );
        } );
    } );
}
catch( err )
{
    console.log( `EXCEPTION-%s`, err.message );
}
```

This works and memory consumption is gone. So, I'm receiving all children of "orders" node + receiving new orders coming + memory is low yay!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attach an `on` listener, the listener stays active until you remove it with `off`. While the listener is active, Firebase will keep an in-memory copy of all data that the listener receives. The memory usage of this in-memory copy/cache can be quite significant, so you should remove your listeners when you don't need the data anymore.

To remove all listeners on a reference:

```
firebase.database().ref("orders").off();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried to use different variations: 

1. .off()
2. .off("child_added")
2. .off("child_added, myfunc)

memory wasn't released in any of these variations.

Add to that a problem which is that I actually need to keep the listener available b/c I need to catch the new orders that are coming after starting the server, so if memory was actually released, I won't be able to listen to new orders coming under that node unless I have that listener running.

Comment: Try `firebase.database().ref("orders").limitToFirst(1).on( "child_added",` to keep listening for new orders. That way the listener only needs to keep a single node in memory. And then use `once("value")` listener to initially get all open orders.

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thanks again, but this new suggestion doesn't work either. I think it's how the limitToFirst(1) works. When I install the listener, I receive the first order under the "orders" node which is expected, but then, when adding a new order, the event won't fire. So, it's like Firebase library tracks how many times it triggered this event and won't exceed that limit. This means that once the first event triggered, you won't receive any further events

Comment: Hmm... it depends on how you add the children. If you add new children at the end, it needs to be `limitToLast(1)`.

Comment: Thanks ... this worked b/c I'm using .push() method to append a new entry to the "orders" node. See my modified question for the final solution I ended-up using.

Comment: THANK YOU FRANK ! Finally after 3 days of memory leaks, it makes sense to turn off the listener! Thank you